# Shortest path when only allowed to move to adjacent nodes in grid-like maze

Tags: shortest-path, path-finding, maze

I searched up many different algorithms, and yet nothing seems to fit into my situation.

I have a situation where:

1. the agent can only move up,down,right,left (4-directions)
2. the agent knows the Manhattan distance between the current node it's standing on and goal node.
3. the agent knows the Manhattan distance between the current node's neighbors and the goal node.
4. grid-like maze where cost of moving is 1 (i.e., every edge is of weight 1)

I tried using A* algorithm. However, the problem is that, in my situation, the agent cannot teleport or jump to the prioritized node if that node is not the neighbor of the current node. This means that when there are two nodes with same priority, the agent might select one that ends up in a dead-end (the previous node is in the "closed" or "settled" set to which the agent cannot move, and the agent is also surrounded by the wall).
In other words, with A* algorithm, back-tracking is impossible due to the movement restriction.

I have also looked at D*-Lite and LPA*, but I don't think they are applicable to my situation (or are they?)

What path finding algorithm should be used in such settings? Thank you.

Comment: If you're trying to simulate an agent solving a maze (without access to the top-down view of the maze), then the algorithm is a depth-first search (DFS).

Answer (score 0):

A* is exactly the algorithm you want. The "teleport" you mentioned only happens internally as part of the search.  The output of the algorithm is the path your unit will take, which won't involve any teleports.

If your unit is revealing the map as it moves around, you'll want to re-run A* every time the map changes.  This problem is extremely common in robotics, so LPA* was designed for exactly this situation - it does the same thing as A*, but reuses information from previous searches to speed up subsequent searches.  However, it's also more complicated to implement, so I'd recommend starting out with just plain old A* and moving to LPA* only if A* is too slow for your needs.